# Opencart new version not working on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I was given an Opencart website that was on a live server so I can run on my localhost(xampp).

Initially, I had changed both config files to this:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://safetyelite.co.za/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://safetyelite.co.za/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://safetyelite.co.za/admin/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://safetyelite.co.za/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://safetyelite.co.za/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/system/logs/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'safetyelite');
define('DB_PREFIX', '');
?>
```

Then in my index.php I changed the website directory:

```
if (!defined('DIR_APPLICATION')) {
    header('Location: /http://localhost/safetyelite/install/index.php');
    exit;
}

// VirtualQMOD
require_once('vqmod/vqmod.php');
$vqmod = new VQMod();
```

When I refreshed the page it gave me this error:

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\safetyelite\system\database\mysql.php on line 6

My config files and index.php look like this now and I don't know what else to do so I hope you can help:
```

Then I upgraded my vqmod folder to the latest one.

In my config files I changed
`define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');`

for this: 
`define('DB_DRIVER', 'mmysqli');`

the `mysqli` file looks like this:

```
<?php
final class mMySQLi {
    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

        if ($this->mysqli->connect_error) {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not make a database link (' . $this->mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $this->mysqli->connect_error);
        }

        $this->mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $query = $this->mysqli->query($sql);

        if ($this->mysqli->errno) {
            trigger_error('Error: ' . $this->mysqli->error . '<br />Error No: ' . $this->mysqli->errno . '<br />' . $sql);
            exit();
        }

        if ($query) {
            if (isset($query->num_rows)) {
                $result = new stdClass();
                $data = array();

                while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }

                $result->row = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : array();
                $result->rows = $data;
                $result->num_rows = $query->num_rows;

                $query->close();

                unset($data);

                return $result;
            } else {
                // When MySQLi returns boolean true instead of a result object
                // http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
                $result = new stdClass();
                $result->row = array();
                $result->rows = array();
                $result->num_rows = 0;

                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            trigger_error('Error: ' . $this->mysqli->error . '<br />Error No: ' . $this->mysqli->errno . '<br />' . $sql);
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function escape($value) {
        return $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($value);
    }

    public function countAffected() {
        return $this->mysqli->affected_rows;
    }

    public function getLastId() {
        return $this->mysqli->insert_id;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }
}
?>
```

When I refresh the page, I see no more errors but everything is blank. I checked with the inspector and all is blank.
Is there anything I am possibly missing?

Hope you can help.

Comment: Open error log.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using linux (ubuntu) you can check the error log for clue.

in terminal type :

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Refer below snapshot

[image]

Using this you will get some clue. I think you have PHP version 7.* , in which Mysql old functions are deprecated.

Comment: am using php 5.3

Comment: Sorry, how can I check that?

Comment: Yes.Thank you....I just checked the error log, but all the dates there are for 2013..nothing for this year

Comment: Do it like this, open the error log in terminal  and try open your page in which you are getting the issue. It will log new error and you will get to know what is wrong